# Extracting the value of a repeater element to prepopulate text box on a modal pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Here is the definition text box on a modal pop up.

```
<asp:TextBox MaxLength="20" runat="server" id="tbName" style="visibility:visible;display:inline;"/>
```

The following jQuery construct is able to extract the value in the repeater element and pre-populate tbName

```
 $("[id$=tbName]").val($.trim($('#revListTitle_' + rowIndex).text()));
```

But the following jQuery construct is not populating tbName.

```
$("#tbName").val($.trim($('#revListTitle_' + rowIndex).text()));
```

My question is:

What is the difference between `$("[id$=tbName]").val("something") and $("#tbName").val("something");`

Answer (score 0):

The function of `document.getElementById()` is only well defined for things that are HTML.

In your case, `<asp:TextBox ... />` is strictly not HTML (different namespace) and will therefore fail to be referenced by an identifier.

Comment: What is the difference between $("[id$=tbName]").val("something") and $("#tbName").val("something"); the first construct works whereas the second one does not

Comment: The first selects the element based on the attribute "id" (i.e. it selects all elements until a match is found) whereas the second tries to find an HTML element directly by its id. However, document doesn't recognise the tag you're using and so does not index its id. @Code